# Symfony2 - 'The class XXX was not found in the chain configured namespaces

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I get following error in Symfony2 application

> 'The class 'Stocksolutions\ShopBundle\Entity\Image' was not found in the chain configured namespaces StockSolutions\UserBundle\Entity, StockSolutions\ShopBundle\Entity, Vlabs\MediaBundle\Entity, FOS\UserBundle\Model'

which is kind of strange imho, because `StockSolutions\ShopBundle\Entity` IS in the configured namespaces. This error appeared when I installed the vlabs media-bundle.

Here my image entity

```
<?php

namespace Stocksolutions\ShopBundle\Entity; 

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Vlabs\MediaBundle\Entity\BaseFile as VlabsFile;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Stocksolutions\ShopBundle\Entity\Image
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="image")
*/
class Image extends VlabsFile
{
    /**
     * @var string $path
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="path", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Image()
     */
    private $path;

    /**
     * Set path
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @return Image
     */
    public function setPath($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;

            return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get path
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }
}
```

I have `auto_mapping: true` in the config.yml file.

Anyone who's familiar with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should write

```
namespace StockSolutions\ShopBundle\Entity;
```

instead of

```
 namespace Stocksolutions\ShopBundle\Entity;
```